# What is the correct way to write a class that pulls in sub-classes (methods) from several files

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pylint

I have written a class as a central data management engine for a register map.  I have written sub-classes (well more like extensions) which provide various input parsers and output formatters.  However they rely on being able to access the internal variables of the main class in order to operate. I would like to keep the extensions separate from the main class but be able to advertise all the methods to the instantiator of the main class.

It all works fine actually except that I get many errors from Pylint of the form:
    E:275, 8: Instance of 'RegMapXLS' has no 'log' member (no-member)
where log is a shared function in the main class.

```
# typical "extension" class
class RegMapXLS():
    ''' The part of RegisterMap class which contains the xlsx source file
        parsing functions
    '''

    def parse_config(self, configsheet):

# main class including all "extension class inherritance"
class RegisterMap(RegMapXLS, RegMapPy, RegMapDocx, RegMapVhdl):
    '''Register map bundling settings as instances of the class Setting.
    '''

    # only this class has an __init__ call to instantiate it and its code
    def __init__(self, name, output_path, report=None):
```

I could of course write the whole thing as one big class but for maintainability reasons I have split them up into several files.  The other way would be to write a "base class" which all the "sister"-classes inherit and create an empty class which simply inherits all of the parts (though its not clear then how I call the **init** method 2 levels down).  My question is what is the best/Pythonic way and for maintenance and readability.

What I want in the end is a simple UI where I can write:

```
with RegisterMap(udi, output_path=output_path) as regmap:
    regmap.parse_source(regmap_source)

    #these methods are pulled in from other source files/authors
    regmap.export_HDF5(output_path)
    regmap.to_vhdl(regmap_reg_pkg_template)
    regmap.to_pin()
    regmap.to_docx(doc_template=doc_template)
```

Comment: I should add that the error messages I am getting are from Pylint.  Python itself is happy.

Comment: You realize your are doing inheritance wrong right? Parents don't inherit subclasses, subclasses inherit parents...  I.e. if `RegMapXLS` is a child than it should inherit `RegisterMap` which is not the way you currently have it.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse, You are correct, I have the whole parent/child thing back to front; in my case they are sister classes that are neither parent nor child. That's why I am calling upon learn-ed fellows like yourself to teach me how to do it properly.  Working in practice is fine but I want to learn how to be a guru :o).

Comment: Your extension classes resemble mix-ins, but the use case for a mix-in is code that could be used by multiple, unrelated classes. Here, I would need more convincing that splitting `RegisterMap` across multiple files would actually serve any benefit.

Comment: @chepner.If I put everything in the same class it would be about 2000 lines long and Pylint would tell me that the module is too long.  I could restructure it as a class and several individual programs which act on the class as constructors and translators but the user would then not have the convenience of a single import and having all methods tied to the data which is what I have at the moment.